# 3d Way Finding Mapping

Tags: java, mapping, java-3d

Hello there guys and gals

I'm just little bit confused about creating simple way finding using the java programming language?
Or is it possible in java? I want to create a simple way finding just like [these](http://vimeo.com/20201532)

Do you have any suggestions for this particular matter?

Comment: This is not formed enough to be a "java (programming) question".  It is essentially asking "How do I write a program that does (big general area)?".  There are various libraries for 3d operations in Java; if you study them a bit you will discover that there is no "simple way" to do anything close to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a shortest-path algorithm and a matrix-builder from the way-points of your map. Java 3D has built-in primitive shapes such as cylinders, spheres and cubes. But you can make your own geometry from points, triangles and quads. See some of the java3D tagged questions in SO.

In java3D, mouse and keyboard interaction is very easy implemented.
Collision detection is also a good pro of java3D while not having a shadow lib being a con.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [3D Wayfinder](http://3dwayfinder.com). They have a public API and fully featured 3d wayfinding. Its not in Java but uses HTML5, WebGL and JavaScript. Yiu have to upload just a floor plan model and are good to go.